# Recently updated partitions in hive

Tags: hive

Is there a way in Hive SQL to **get all partitions updated after a specific time** ?

I have hourly partitions based on transaction time. It is very much likely that a transaction record arrives few hours late, and it reaches an older partition.

```
Table1 : Hourly partitions
00
01
..
23

Table 2 : Daily partitions
After midnight above 24 partitions are aggregated into daily partition in Table2.
```

After this daily partition was created, a set of transactions **arrive late** and they are added into Table1 hourly parition.
Say they are added in hour=20 partition.

I need to identify what all partitions received late updates in this manner. So if there is a need I will recalculate my daily partition data in Table2.

Answer (score 1):

I would introduce intermediate table with two columns: day and last modified time. Every time late records arrive, update this table with new rows of last update time.

Table2 can use this table to check if last modified time > job last execution time. If so, do calculation for that day.

Comment: can you please provide some sample table like what you have and what you want.

Comment: Hi Jayashree, the requirement is more about the partitions than the data. In a nutshell I want to "get all partitions updated after a specific time ?" as described in the beginning of the question.

Comment: Hi Rumoku, Thanks for the updates. Yes my current solution is by having parent partition of last_update_time, which helps in getting the delta data. ie. Application is handling this. But looking for a Hive native solution if there is any.

Comment: Using `describe formatted` for table partition you can definitely extract created time and also last access time, not sure if there is a possibility to extract last modification time (maybe one of above represents it). You can explore this approach!

Comment: Rumoku `describe formatted` did not help me identify the last updated time of partitions.